# Set up SyncTeX with Emacs DocView

Tags: emacs, forward-inverse-search

I have the source in one emacs buffer and the compiled pdf in another DocView buffer with auto-revert-mode enabled. Using `latexmk -pvc` to compile gives me live previews. Now I want to setup forward and inverse search. All the instructions I can find about using emacs with synctex involves some external viewer. Is there any way to do this at all?

Comment: I am assuming this is not possible based upon zero information in Google, except for a couple of comments here and there stating that they too believe it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools).  It adds support for forward and inverse search using synctex.  Quoting the commentary in one of the synctex related functions:

```
Correlate a PDF position with the TeX file.
\\<pdf-sync-minor-mode-map>
This works via SyncTeX, which means the TeX sources need to have
been compiled with `--synctex=1'. In AUCTeX this can be done by
setting `TeX-source-correlate-method' to 'synctex \(before AUCTeX
is loaded\) and enabling `TeX-source-correlate-mode'.

Then \\[pdf-sync-mouse-goto-tex] in the PDF buffer will open the
corresponding TeX location.

If AUCTeX is your preferred tex-mode, this library arranges to
bind `pdf-sync-tex-display-pdf-key' \(the default is `C-c C-g'\)
to `pdf-sync-display-pdf' in `TeX-source-correlate-map'. This
function displays the PDF page corresponding to the current
position in the TeX buffer. This function only works together
with AUCTeX.
```

After setting up AUCTex, yous should be able to forward search with `C-c C-g`  and reverse search by double clicking on the pdf in doc-view (with pdf-tools enabled; i.e. invoke `pdf-tools-enable` first).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this configuration file for `latexmk`:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -src-specials -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error %O %S";
$pdf_previewer = "start evince %O %S";
$pdf_update_method = 0;
$sleep_time = 1;
$recorder = 1;
```

and this in the `.emacs`

```lisp
;;correlate
(server-start)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
```

Comment: does that open doc-view or evince?